# Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist is not supported

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors, compilation

I got the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Console_main__.gradle' line: 18

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'demo'.
> Could not create task ':Console.main()'.
   > Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist is not supported.  Use create() or register() directly instead.  You attempted to replace a task named 'Console.main()', but there is no existing task with that name.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 236ms
10:32:59 PM: Task execution finished 'Console.main()'.
```

Comment: I know that this is old now but one way that I was able to fix this was by going to gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties and changing the distributionUrl to use a gradle distribution prior to Gradle 6. Hopefully, this comment can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Clear the cache and start the app again. This might happen when you recently upgraded gradle.
If you are on intellij idea then choose file -> invalidate cache and restart.

If you are using gradle then delete your .gradle folder and run gradle again.

Comment: It's not working after Invalidate Cache and Restart

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Intellij idea, this might help:
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Build and run using: IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use well formatted code and try to give a good description of your answer so that it would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 12):

Quoting an answer on a GitHub issue for the Gradle project from [November 15th 2019](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11371#issuecomment-554553932):

> This is coming from a long deprecated behavior that was finally made an error in Gradle 6.0. Unfortunately, we're not going to restore the old behavior, but we'll work with JetBrains to make this sort of thing work without requiring special handling on IDEA's side.
>
> This is already fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 (in beta now). If you can upgrade to the 2019.3 EAP or beta, this should work there.

Update IntelliJ to the latest stable version to fix this issue. At the time of this writing, 2019.3.1 is the latest stable release of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: going back to gradle-5.6.4 helped me overcome this issue

Comment: Updating Intellij to the latest version has fixed this issue for me.

Comment: As of June 2020, I had this issue in version of IntelliJ Idea 2019.2.4, but after updating to the latest version (2020.1.2) the issue got resolved

Comment: @PrasanthRajendran yes, updating to 2019.3.1 or later should resolve the issue, unless a regression is introduced in the future.

Answer (score 5):

I tried everything, only this guy's [solution](https://webgori.github.io/spring/2020/03/21/Spring-Unnecessarily-replacing-a-task-that-does-not-exist-is-not-supported.html) worked for me.

The solution is pretty straight forward. Instead of build and run using gradle, choose, build and run using Intellij.

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. Change the value of build and run using from gradle to Intellij: [image]
4. This is how it should look like: [image]

Comment: Please don't answer with a link, as links can go stale. Instead, formulate a synopsis of what the linked site is saying and put it in your answer, and then provide a link to the site as the source of the information.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Fixed my mistake. Thanks for pointing out. Screenshots with synopsis has been added for future reference of others.

Comment: Reverted my downvote, thanks for updating the answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me I solved the issue by using local gradle distribution settings instead of default gradle wrapper. This settings is in Buil, Execution, Deployment > gradle section.

Answer (score 0):

From the link:https://chewett.co.uk/blog/2420/fixing-gradle-error-unnecessarily-replacing-a-task-that-does-not-exist-is-not-supported/

This error relates to using Gradle 6 with IntelliJ 2019.2 or older. This means to fix the issue you just need to upgrade to IntelliJ 2019.3 or newer.

If this isn’t possible you are able to downgrade gradle to the latest version 5 distribution. This should also resolve the issue.

I upgraded from intellij 19.1 to 2021.2.4 and everything got fixed.